# Spring Batch Integration - Multiple files as single Message

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

In the sample https://github.com/ghillert/spring-batch-integration-sample, the file inbound adapter is configured to poll for a directory and once the file is placed in that directory, a FileMessageToJobRequest is constructed and the Spring batch Job is getting launched. 
So for each file, a new FileMessageToJobRequest is constructed and a new Spring batch Job instance is getting created.

We also want to configure a file inbound adapter to poll for the files but want to process all the files using a single batch job instance.
For example, If we place 1000 files in the directory and have max-messages-per-poll to 1000, We want to send the name of the 1000 files as one of the parameters to Spring batch Job instead of calling the Job 1000 times.
Is there a way to send list of files that the File Inbound adapter picked up during its one poll as a single message to the subsequent Spring components?

Thank You,
Regards 
Suresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it is a `single poll`, the `inbound-channel-adapter` emits messages for each entry.

So, to collect them to the single message you need to use an `<aggregator>`.

Although with that you have to come up with `ReleaseStrategy`. Even if you can just use `1` as a `correlationKey`, there is some issue with releasing the group.

You should agree with that you don't always have `1000` of files there to group them to the single message. So, maybe a `TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` is a good compromise to emit the result after some `timeout`, even if you don't have enough number of files to complete the group by size.

HTH

**UPDATE**

You can consider to use `group-timeout` on the `<aggregator>` to allow to release groups even if there is no a new message during that period.

In addition the there is an `expire-groups-upon-completion` option to be sure that you "single" will be cleared and removed after each `release`. To allow to form a new group for the next `poll`.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I will try the aggregator strategy and let know.